# How to improve multiple queries

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

**Objective:** i would like to make a total for my simple Coin Betting System.

- **Total Member with Coin Deposit:** displays count of all members who make a deposit transaction.
- **Total Member with Coin Withdrawal:** displays count of all members who make a withdrawal transaction.
- **Total Number of Bets:** displays count of all bets
- **Total Member with Coin Balance:** display count of all members who still coin balance.

**Code:** Long cut

```
MYSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT member_id"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " FROM GameActivityReport"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " WHERE CoinDeposit > 0"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Debug.Print MYSQL
rs.Open MYSQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
With MainWindow
    If rs.EOF Then
    Else
        .lblCheckerKPITotPWD.Caption = rs.RecordCount
    End If
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

MYSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT member_id"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " FROM GameActivityReport"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " WHERE CoinWithdarawal > 0"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Debug.Print MYSQL
rs.Open MYSQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
With MainWindow
    If rs.EOF Then
    Else
        .lblCheckerKPITotPWW.Caption = rs.RecordCount
    End If
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

MYSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NewCoinDropCount"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " FROM GameActivityReport"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " WHERE CoinDrop > 0"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Debug.Print MYSQL
rs.Open MYSQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
With MainWindow
    If rs.EOF Then
    Else
        .lblCheckerKPITotPWB.Caption = rs.Fields("NewCoinDropCount")
    End If
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

MYSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT member_id"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " FROM GameActivityReport"
MYSQL = MYSQL & " WHERE CoindBalance > 0"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Debug.Print MYSQL
rs.Open MYSQL, db, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
With MainWindow
    If rs.EOF Then
    Else
        .lblCheckerKPITotEC.Caption = rs.RecordCount
    End If
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

**Question:** how can i make my above code to be shortened.

Comment: Maybe you can combine all your queries in a union query.  Of course you need to add one column and tag names to your queries in this column to distinguish the queries.  Just an idea.

Comment: Stack has a sister site for these kind of questions, you'll probably get a better response there: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are these field names correct `CoinWithdarawal` and `CoindBalance` ?

Comment: This would be a better fit for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/, but in its current state wouldn't be acceptable to post there. If you included what you've done so far to make the code shorter along with that the actual task you're trying to accomplish is, with details, then it might be on-topic there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ozgun suggested, create a union query

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub counts()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sql(3) As String, sql_all As String, counts(4) As Integer

    sql(0) = " SELECT 1,COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) FROM GameActivityReport " & _
             " WHERE CoinDeposit > 0"
    sql(1) = " SELECT 2,COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) FROM GameActivityReport " & _
             " WHERE CoinWithdrawal > 0"
    sql(2) = " SELECT 3,COUNT(*) FROM GameActivityReport " & _
             " WHERE CoinDrop > 0"
    sql(3) = " SELECT 4,COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) FROM GameActivityReport " & _
             " WHERE CoinBalance > 0"
  
    sql_all = Join(sql, vbCrLf & " UNION " & vbCrLf)

    ' get connection, run sql
    Set conn = ??? ' establish a connection 
    Set rs = conn.Execute(sql_all)
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        counts(rs(0)) = rs(1)
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    With MainWindow
        .lblCheckerKPITotPWD.Caption = counts(1)
        .lblCheckerKPITotPWW.Caption = counst(2)
        .lblCheckerKPITotPWB.Caption = counts(3)
        .lblCheckerKPITotEC.Caption = counts(4)
    End With
    conn.Close

End Sub
```